# How to save Dashboard XML File to Specific Location in Devexpress?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I am using Devexpress Controls.

I have created one sample app and using Dashboard template from Devexpress control.

I want to save dashboard XML file at specific location. How it is possible?

By default it save in this folder.

```
 DashboardFileStorage dashboardFileStorage = new DashboardFileStorage("~/App_Data");
        ASPxDashboard1.SetDashboardStorage(dashboardFileStorage);
```

I want to save it to physical Path like

"d:/Srusti/XML".

Comment: What happens when you tried?

Comment: It throws an error. It says provide Virtual Path.

Comment: is this a web thing? or a winforms? or what?

Comment: @BugFinder It 's web.

Comment: that will be why then

Comment: So now what? Mr. @BugFinder

Comment: With webstuff they expect you to use virtual paths.. simple as.. (and Im not male!)

Comment: Yeah, But If I want to use another directory then It's not Possible?(sorry for "Mr.")

Comment: it might let you do it as a relative path but I would kinda hope not.

Comment: i think saving dashboard xml is available in devexpress dashboard designer

Comment: @jayvee, Yes right it's available but nor for physical path. Only for virtual path.